# How to add and align buttons on banner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The banner should stay close to the info buttons like in this example:

[image: This marked label should stay inline and left of the buttons]

I want to move this "Ads by Google" label left away from the buttons.

```js
function removeHeader() {
  var list = document.getElementById("main");
  list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.banner-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showme {
  display: none;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.infoLink:hover .showme {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.closeBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

i:hover {
  color: #d075f4;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
    <p>teteasdasdasdsadasds sad asdasdasdasdasdas</p>

    <div class="banner-buttons">
      <label class="showme">Ads by Google</label>
      <a class="infoLink" href="https://support.google.com/adsense/#topic=3373519" target="_blank">
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
      </a>
      <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
        <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

HTML code: Here is the html, you will find the two buttons and icons there. If there is something missing just ask and I will update the post.

Comment: What seems to be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your p to a div and moving it after the other stuff. Then adding CSS to move the ad part:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="nanoSaturnBanner">
    <div class="banner-buttons">
      <label class="showme">Ads by Google</label>
        <a class="infoLink" 
         href="https://support.google.com/adsense/#topic=3373519" 
         target="_blank">
         <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
        </a>
    <div class="closeBtn" onclick="removeHeader()">
     <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="text">teteasdasdasdsadasds sad asdasdasdasdasdas</div>
</div>
```

then add this to the new div class

```
float: right;
margin-right: 50%;
```